# Integration of Images into websites. Images are retireved from external webservices repository

Tags: image, rest, architecture, responsive-design, browser

Could you please help design this scenario effectively.

We have a website which shows transactional data and for each transactional data thumbnail image of the record is shown.

Images will be pulled from the webservices exposed by the external system. External web service provides the link to the image file that needs to be shown as thumbnail.

we show around 250 records at a time. The effectively means browser requests for 250 image request once the path of the image is retrieved from external webservice while rendering the elements.

What is the best way to approach this requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a CDN? If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, this would be an ideal fit ... reducing 250 images requests just has to be good for your server performance.

[CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com) is one of the easiest to setup, [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) has heaps of options and you'll find plenty of other good suppliers as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: David, thanks for you comments. All of the applications are intranet applications, situated on the same network. Multiple applications own different responsibilities and are single point of truth of a functionality. Image distribution service provides images to N-Number of applications in the organizations and we have no control on the content but can just consume restful image web service. Considering these facts, will CDN still help. We are skeptical of the load time it is going to take to render these 200 images, recorsd are displayed in a table which has lazy loading. Please suggest

Comment: @Mallikarjun ...hmmm, I hadn't realised that you're on an itranet. A CDN approach would still be feasible if the thumbnails could be pushed to an external server like Amazon.